# Sorted Linked List constructor

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm implementing a SortedLinkedList class for my data structures class and the Project Javadoc says this for the constructor implementation:

`SortedLinkedList(java.util.Comparator<T> comparator)
Creates an empty list that is associated with the specified comparator.`

I have no idea what this means. What's the role of the comparator if all we have to do is create an empty list? Wouldn't just saying `head=null`within the constructor suffice?

Comment: The comparator presumably determines the order within the list.

Comment: `Sorting` in other words `ordering` requires `Comparator`

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the comparator tells the list how to sort when adding items to the collection.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. So the user will specify what comparing mechanism to use when they first instantiate a SortedLinkedList and the rest of my program should use that particular comparator to do all the insertion, deletion etc? If that's the case. What am I supposed to do with it in the constructor?

Comment: You don't need to use the comparator, the SLL is doing that for you. You're just telling it how you want it sorted. You want to give it a comparator that does reverse alphabetical? You can do that for example.

Comment: I still need to know what comparator the user will be using, no? I did this after coming on here
`private Comparator<T> comp`
and in the constructor did: `this.comp = comparator` So then I can go on to use comp in my addElement method later on and figure out where the insertion should happen. Is this the way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

The structure is a sorted linked list, so you need to be able put an item in its appropriate position within the list when it is entered. This depends on whether or not the items can be ordered naturally. In the case where you are ordering based on Alphabetical Order of Last Name for example, you create the sorted linked list with a comparator. The comparator object specifies how to compare two names. Realize here that the Sorted Linked List is not the same as simply creating a Linked List of items and then sorting it. The idea is that it maintains its own sort and it does so with the comparator.  Saying `head = null` Constructs an empty list but depending what you put in the list, it may not be sufficient to maintain a sorting of objects as they are inserted into the list.